# How to make a user config available to all classes of a module

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python library which is meant to be used as a third party library.

`great_library/__init__.py`:

```
class ClassA(object):

    @cache()
    def foo(self):
        pass

class ClassB(object):

    @cache()
    def bar(self):
        pass

class GreatLibrary(object):

    @classmethod        
    def great_api(cls):
        pass

    # uses ClassA and ClassB
```

this library is used as:

```
from great_library import GreatLibrary
GreatLibrary.great_api()
```

Now the problem is, I'd like the user to config cache expiration time. which should be passed to `@cache()`: `@cache(seconds)`

How should I design this module structure so the user could easily pass in the config and let it be used by classA and classB ? thanks

Comment: `cache` is your own decorator or is from a library?

Comment: @Micheled'Amico it's from another library

Comment: There some API on the other library to set the default cache time?

Comment: i'm afraid there isn't

Answer (score 1):

The base problem is that the variable passed to the decorator will be read when the module will be load. So there are no way to change it before (at least if you don't want to reload the module by some hacking but that cannot change the old objects). So you need some hook where `great_library` can get the value of the cache time and where the user can write the desired value.

The more simple and wide used method is set environment variables. At the top of your `great_library` module you can check the variables and load the default cache time:

```
import os
default_time = os.getenv("GREAT_LIBRARY_CACHE_TIME", None)
```

In your code use `@cache(default_time)`. I'm not sure that the `cache()` API take `None` as default argument, otherwise is simple to modify the receipt to adapt it to your problem.

Now the users of `great_library` can be set it either by `os.putenv()` in devolopment stage (before import the module) or by OS environment in production.

An other way to put an hook can be use a configuration module to import. IMHO that method can be useful only if you have a bunch of property to set. If you follow that path your `great_library` module should implement something of this:

```
try:
    from great_library_config import *
except ImportError:
    # Default configurations like...
    default_time = None
```

Personally I try to avoid solutions like that for a module but can be useful for applications or framework with an high degree of configurability. Anyway also in that case the user can use a config module for production and override it by a developing/testing one.